# Backlinks coming in from strange/unknown referrer

Tags: seo, backlinks

am new on stackexchange, so I apologize in advance if this is the wrong place to post.

I am in the midst of clearing up links to my website and came across this one coming from this site/blog: www.disabledsportsmen.net.  I wrote to the domain registrar, who then pointed me to the IP host which turns out to be Softlayer.

question is, why do people even put up links like this?  this link was not bought or set up in any way by us.  also why would Softlayer be hosting/have a site like this?  Do they even know about it?  Will they be able to remove it if I emailed them to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: I looked at the site briefly. What is your objection to this site having a link to yours??

Comment: Presumably because is spammy, low quality junk/garbage @closetnoc.

Comment: well, the site in question has only 10 articles, dealing with iphones, real estate, roman blinds and SAP.  while I don't have hard evidence that it's damaging my site's reputation, I'm quite certain I don't want such a random looking site with an even more random URL having a link to my site  :)

Comment: Yes. But that happens everyday by the thousands. This one seemed rather benign to me. The last thing I would get my nickers in a twist over. Any site will in time get thousands of junk sites linking to them. Google knows the spam sites and does not count them against you. Spam sites will never remove your link even if you ask. They do not care. The way your question read to me was that it was something horrible like a transgender adult/child bestiality BDSM latex fetish site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Softlayer (just from searching on google) is a company that rents out server space to their customers to host websites. Anyone can sign up with them if they have sufficient money.

There's a couple of possibilities as to why www.disabledsportsmen.net appeared as a referrer in your server logs.

1. Someone may have submitted a story about your website to a page on www.disabledsportsmen.net along with images hot-linked to your server. This means any guest that loads the story in their browser will automatically load the image from YOUR server to their browser. Matters are far worse if you do not implement any proper caching with any of the images.
2. There may be a special program installed on the computer associated with the IP address thats associated with www.disabledsportsmen.net. The special program is then set to download items from your website. If you see tons of entries from this URL in your server log and the time printed for each entry is very similar (where each entry is up to one second away from the last), then its definitely a program from the server doing it. The actual name for the people behind this kind of operation are known as "script kiddies".

As for your last question, If the reason for the entry in your logs is what I described in #1 above, then contact the people at www.disabledsportsmen.net and ask them to remove all entries containing any direct links to any element of your site. If however the reason is #2 then you'll need to limit access to the IP address or block access depending on whether or not legit users also use that IP address to connect to you.

Comment: Furthermore, if any links exist from that domain `disabledsportsmen.net` to the OP's website, then they ought to be removed/disavowed as the blog is a splog (spam blog) probably operated by some clueless SEO company anyway so could potentially  cause harm, especially if one/multiple of many like this.

Comment: thank you for the replies, Mike and zigojacko.  I've written in to ask for the link to be removed, but I doubt if it will be of help.  I will also check further and block the IP if really necessary.  and yes, I've already disavowed the that domain :)

Comment: I advise avoiding the disavow link as much as possible for two reasons: one, Google does say that spam sites largely will not drag down your site; and two, Google advises that the disavow tool is essentially a last resort tool that should be used with caution and not necessarily intended for ordinary links  but for toxic links. A single link from a spam site is not toxic- nor is 1000 links from the same site.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of different reasons people link to your site. If it's a spammy domain, you don't need to worry about the reason why, because it's certainly not to improve UX. If you don't want the site linking to you, just disavow it in Webmaster tools, don't waste your time writing to a spammy domain who probably won't answer back.

Also, this is a great tool to cross reference domains you're unsure that you should disavow or not: https://www.disavowfiles.com/